# Session handling in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have asked to do a session handling between IFrame and parent window both are in different domain so I started with a POC with 2 HTML pages one is parent window and another to open in Iframe as dialog window in button click.

From the dialog window, passing post message at time interval. Validating the message in parent window by throwing an error message. Below are my code snippets and which I took from the Google surf.

**Parent Window:**

```
<script>
    function openFrame() {
        var iFrame=window.showModalDialog('Iframe.html');
    }

    window.onmessage = function(e){
        if (e.data == 'maintainSession') {
            alert('Active in main!');
        }
    };
</script>

<button id="openFrame" onclick="openFrame()">Open Frame</button>
```

**Iframe Page:**

```
<script>
    window.setInterval(window.top.postMessage('maintainSession', '*'), 10000);          
</script>
```

Problem is ..I'm not getting alert after 10 seconds . So can anyone help me to resolve what I'm doing work here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of setInterval is expected to be a function.

```
window.setInterval(function(){ window.top.postMessage('maintainSession', '*'); }, 10000);
```

You were executing the postMessage immediately and giving to setInterval whatever the return of postMessage() is.

Comment: I'm not able to get the alert :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe your parent window must be itself inside some another iframe or something this is mostly the case if you are using plugins like bootstrap,colorbox or trying out online like jsfiddle etc you can get the immediate parent of iframe if you use `parent` inside it `parent.postMessage(message, '*');`

Comment: When I try in Firefox developer tool, window.top or parent both are reading the Iframe page not the parent window .. :( so that's issue I believe